# Coordinate system transformation

Tags: python-3.x, mapping, python-xarray, cartopy, map-projections

I have data on a grid made by matlab with putpole and rotatem.
I don't have access to the original data but would like to work with Python on it.
The origin of the grid is 78 and 11 degrees (star marker) but plotting with cartopy it always puts the North Pole in the middle, so my data are a little off.

Does someone know how to fix it?
I tried with the false_northing but that doesn't do anything. Please ignore the horrible colorbar I am just playing around trying to fix the map.

```
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')

    #plotting settings
    ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 40, 90], ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.gridlines(linewidth=2, color='k', alpha=0.7, linestyle='--')
    ax.coastlines(zorder=3)

    ZEP_coords=(78.9,11.8)
    ax.plot(ZEP_coords,'*',c='orangered', markersize=25, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    data_mod, lon_mod = add_cyclic_point(a, coord=lon)
    plt.contourf(lon_mod,lat,data_mod,20,vmin=0,     vmax=0.05,cmap=cmap,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    plt.colorbar()
```

plot how it looks like at the moment:

[image: img1]

data structure and all infos I have:

[image: img2]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `NorthPolarStereo`, if you use `Stereographic` as your projection you can specify both the central latitude and longitude. You may also want to look at the `RotatedPole` projection.

Comment: I tried Stereographic, also with false_easting and false_northing, my plot does not change at all. And with Rotated Pole I get a very weird plot and still the origin is put on the North Pole and not on my Station. I am not sure if that is super clear in my question but my polar stereographic coordinates originate from a different lat,lon. These "easy" fixes don't work. I just found the function ccrs.crs.RotatedGeodetic(pole_longitude, pole_latitude, central_rotated_longitude=0.0, globe=None), will give that a go tomorrow morning. In case someone has a nice example please provide it here :)

Comment: I got a step further with calculating the meshgrid from matlab, but the data are getting weird in cartopy, reproduced the same with basemap and it works just fine. I guess open for development. I will contact cartopy directly now.